# IIS 7: How do I install Bugzilla?

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis-7, bugzilla

I have Bugzilla 4 and I need to get it to run on a Windows Server 2008 running IIS 7. I've looked at various tutorials with no luck. Please direct me on how to setup Bugzilla!

Comment: Where are you stuck? I've got this running but need more information to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl + MySQL on Windows Server 2008 + IIS 7 isn't the best fit.

Have you considered installing Apache on Windows Server and either disabling IIS or sticking them on different ports?

Pretty straightforward looking official tutorial [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install).

An alternative might be to stick Bugzilla on an Ubuntu VM. Installation [looks like this](http://vibhurishi.blogspot.com/2009/05/howto-install-bugzilla-on-ubuntu-9.html).

Comment: .... Ok thanks for the help. I think we may wind up writing our own bug tracker. ... :-)

Comment: Considered BugTracker.NET?

Comment: Did you find this answered your question? Would you mind marking it as answered if you found it did please?

Comment: @Toom. The answer was that yes it can run on IIS 6, but I could not find any reliable information to get it to work on IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get Bugzilla running on IIS7+

I started by following the directions at:
http://lpsolit.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/make-bugzilla-work-with-iis7-easy/

I will write a simplified version below in English, assuming you already created the website/virtual directory:

1.) Click on the Bugzilla site 
2.) Go to Handler Mappings 
3.) Click Add Script Map from the right-side bar 
    Request Path = *.cgi 
    Executable: C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -x"D:\www\Bugzilla" -T %s

```
* Take note there is no space between -x, I had the space and it caused a 502 error about incomplete headers
```

3.b) Click OK and you should be prompted to add this rule to the ISAPI extension. Click Yes. 
4.) Go back to the Bugzilla site 
5.) Go to Default Document 
6.) Set index.cgi as the only page.

Now try to access your Bugzilla site. You should see it load up.

The goal of the setup is to enable CGI executables to run under IIS with Perl setup to run a specific command for Bugzilla. You don't need to open up full access to CGI (which is insecure) by doing the steps above. The method I outlined just opens up the only permissions needed by Bugzilla.

So really, the whole install on Bugzilla is pretty simple, with the only issues I ran into was some optional Perl modules are not yet compiled on Windows. I had to use ActivePerl 5.14 to get all the required modules working.